# Standard UK visit visa long term visit visa selection issue - new application form

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, applications, long-term

I'm applying for a long term standard UK visitor visa from India. I have completed till the Declaration section, but till here no where I found any option for the visa length (6 months, 2 years, 3 years etc). I want to apply for a 2 years visitor visa so that I can visit UK multiple times to visit my daughter and her family in the UK.

I am applying through the link https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

Will I be getting an option for the visa duration in the pay tab, or am I using the  wrong link?

Comment: Have you successfully applied for a UK visitor visa before?

Answer (score 3):

[This UK govt page](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) notes that the fee charged depends on visa duration. The text is:

> **Fees**
>
> A Standard Visitor visa costs £95.
>
> The fee for a long-term Standard Visitor visa depends on its length:
>
> 2 years - £361
>
> 5 years - £655
>
> 10 years - £822

When you get to the "payments" page, you'll have to choose the amount of the payment, and thereby specify the visa duration you seek.